# R program open file directly based on name assigned in code

Tags: r, dataframe, openxlsx

I have code in which initially it ask's the user to type the data file name and assign it for variable nm and select the reference file name. I want to convert it into arguments that will directly assigned the data file to variable nm and automatically select the reference file based on the name that is entered in the argument.

i've tried this so far but it still feels manual.

```
library("openxlsx")
nm=readline("Enter  data file name:tdd_data4.xlsx") 
readline("Enter input file name: (Press Enter)")
input_file=read.xlsx(file.choose(tdd_rinput2.xlsx))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this. But this requires the user to type in the whole file path. I assumed one in the solution below.

```
nm <- readline("Enter data file name: (press enter to continue)")
input_file <- read.csv(file.path("C:/Users/Desktop", nm))
```

Comment: Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\P" i am getting this error

Comment: You need to use the other slash / instead of \. Please vote/accept if answer was helpful, thanks!